# Camera Intent not working with multiple camera apps

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

In my app I run camera intent to take picture with photo App, with this code below:

```
Activity activity;
File currentPhotoFile;
Intent capturePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri uri = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, activity.getPackageName() + providerSufixName, currentPhotoFile);
capturePhoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
activity.startActivityForResult(capturePhoto, REQUEST_PHOTO);
```

And after that I catch the created photo in my `activity.onActivityResult` function in Activity

If I have only one! photo App on my mobile device - everything works fine.

But! If I installed on my device one more! photo application - the code above is not working :(

In case two photo apps, when I call `activity.startActivityForResult` - I see andoid system dialog with list of all available photo apps. (like Intent.createChooser calling). I select from it, preferable photo app and tap "JUST ONCE". Selected application runs, I take picture inside it and press Ok button for returning back to my App. 
At this moment I recieve callback to my `onActivityResult` with my code: `REQUEST_PHOTO` but with `requestCode = RESULT_CANCELED`. And that's all :(

Why it's not working? 
And how I can resolve this issue and use camera intent with more than one photo application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in manifest I have option: 
`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` for my activity.

```
<activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
>
```

For solving above issue you should remove `singleInstance` option from manifest file (or replace it within `singleTask` option). 
This is resolve the issue and `onActivityResult` is properly working.